# how to add two images in a drawer in react navigation 6 (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
drawerIcon: () => (
  <Image
    resizeMode="center"
    style={styles.logos}
    source={require("../assets/images/drawable-xxxhdpi/profile_logo.png")}
  />
);
```

im putting drawericon but it is overriding

Answer (score 0):

The drawer icon of a drawer screen is passed via the `options` prop in the `drawerIcon` attribute as follows.

```js
<Drawer.Screen name="Test" component={Test} options={{
           title: 'Test',
           drawerIcon: ({focused, size}) => (
              <Image resizeMode='center' style={styles.logos} source={require('../assets/images/drawable-xxxhdpi/profile_logo.png')} />
           ),
        }}/>
```